# Excel VBA Formula German/French/Italian/Russian/Dutch/Foreign Function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

When I add data to my workbook it is necassary to copy the formula from an earlier cell to the new cell(s).

I used the following formula to calculate my growth rate:

```
=WENN(ODER(K9="";L9="");"";WENNFEHLER((L9-K9)/K9;""))
```

Since this is very time consuming I want to improve it with a macro and have therefor written the following code:

```
Sub Growth()

Tabelle3.Range("O9").Formula = "=WENN(ODER(K9="";L9="");"";WENNFEHLER((L9-K9)/K9;""))"

Tabelle3.Range("O9:O14").FillDown


End Sub
```

However, when I want to run the code "runtime error '1004': application defined or object defined error" occours for this line:

```
Tabelle3.Range("O9").Formula = "=WENN(ODER(K9="";L9="");"";WENNFEHLER((L9-K9)/K9;""))"
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two main errors in the code - not escapting the `"` characters and using `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaLocal`. The `"` characters should be written twice to show once in a string. See this code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print "test"""""
End Sub
```

It prints `test""`. The last `"` is for the end of the string. Concerning the formula, use `.FormulaLocal` if you want to use the German formulas and double the doublequotes:

```
Range("O9").FormulaLocal = "=WENN(ODER(K9="""";L9="""");"""";WENNFEHLER((L9-K9)/K9;""""))"
```

In general, avoid using `.FormulaLocal` and use `.Formula`, to make your VBA code compatible with a workbook from Italy or France from example. Something like this will work with any local settings in Excel:

`Range("O9").Formula = "=IF(OR(K9="""",L9=""""),"""",IFERROR(((K9-K9)/K9),""""))"`

---

What I usually do is the following:

1. Write the formula, so it works in Excel;
2. Select it manually;
3. Run this:

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

4. It prints the formula as it should look like in the immediate window;
5. Copy it;
6. In the code above you may replace `Selection.Formula` with one of the following three (Consider as an example `=IF(B1=C1,""Equal"",""Not Equal"")`

   - `Selection.FormulaLocal` (gets the local formula `=WENN()` for Germany)
     `=WENN(B1=C1;""Equal"";""Not equal"")`
   - `Selection.FormulaR1C1` (gets formula in R1C1 format)
     `=IF(RC[1]=RC[2],""Equal"",""Not equal"")`
   - `Selection.FormulaR1C1Local` (gets R1C1 format with local formulas)
     `=WENN(ZS(1)=ZS(2);"Equal";"Not equal")`

Comment: 10x @Vityata for your help :)

Comment: I also tried to extend my Range from Tabelle3.Range("O9:O14").FillDown to Tabelle3.Range("O9:O").FillDown. It occurs "runtime error 1004 method 'range' of object '_workbook' failed". Do you probably know whats wrong with this one too? :) @Vityata

Comment: @HPM - you need to have a normal range. E.g. `Range("O:O")` or `Range(O1:O5)`. `Range(O1:O)` is illegal. This is something good to read - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm