# Writing a formula with concatenated parts into a cell

Tags: vba, excel

**Scenario:** I have a code that should write a formula to a worksheet cells. This formula is for an API to retrieve some value. My formula is inside a loop (this is done for multiple columns) and references the first row for an identifier.

**The original formula:**

```
=FS(B1;"FI(DATE,,DATE)")
```

**The modified formula with the floating reference (inside the loop):**

```
For i = 1 To lColumn
    If wb.Worksheets("Dates").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        wb.Worksheets("Dates").Cells(i,2).value = "=FS(" & i & "1;"FI(DATE,,DATE)")"
    End If
Next i
```

Where lColumn is some pre-defined number.

**Issue:** I keep getting the "Unexpected end of statement" error in the formula part of the loop.

**What I already tried:** I tried different variations, repositioning the "s and 's, for example:

```
wb.Worksheets("Dates").Cells(i,2).value = "'"=FS(" & i & "1;"FI(DATE,,DATE)")""
```

or

```
wb.Worksheets("Dates").Cells(i,2).value = "'=FS(" & i & "1;"FI(DATE,,DATE)")"
```

or

```
wb.Worksheets("Dates").Cells(i,2).value = "'""=FS(" & i & "1;"FI(DATE,,DATE)")"
```

and so on. But the error still persists.

**Question:** What is the proper way to do this operation?

Comment: What is a floating reference?

Comment: @Vityata "i", since it changes in the loop.

Comment: Can you take a look here and try to do the steps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363434/excel-vba-formula-german-french-italian-russian-dutch-foreign-function/49363501#49363501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with formulas in VBA is a little bit tricky:

- To write a formula, use the `range.formula` property, not the `.value`.
- You have to write the formula as if you are using an english Excel. Parameter-separator is comma (not semicolon).
- If a formula needs a quote, double it so that the VBA compiler understands that you want a quote within a string.
- I find it helpfull to write a formula into a variable before assigning it - you can check in the debugger if it is exactly how it should before assigning it.
- To check how the formula should look like, write it into a cell, change to the VBA-editor, open the *immediate window* and write `? activecell.formula`

Try (untested as the formula you need is not valid to us):

```
with wb.Worksheets("Dates")
  dim f as string, adr as string
  adr = cells(i, 1).address(false, false)   ' get rid of Dollar signs
  f = "=FS(" & adr & ",""FI(DATE,,DATE)"")"
  .Cells(i, 2).formula = f
end with
```

Comment: I think it should be `adr = cells(1, i).address(false, false)` as it's the column that's changing, not the row

Comment: @Pi: Probably you're right - copied this part from OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
wb.Worksheets("Dates").Cells(i,2).formula = "=FS(" & Cells(1, i).Address(0,0) & ";""FI(DATE,,DATE)"")"
```

There may be a better way to convert the column number to a letter (which is the problem you are having, along with the double quotes)!

Comment: Instead of using replace, consider using the parameters of `Address` to return a relative reference (ie without `$`'s)

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen, wasn't aware of that. Will update my answer :0)

Comment: Do not write a formula into `.value` - use `.formula` instead

Comment: @FunThomas. You are quite right. I was focusing on the right hand side far too much!