# VBA error code 1004 using a SUMIF formula

Tags: vba

I need your help.
I am writing this small piece of code in VBA to use in a an RPA proces.
I have tested my formula in Excel and it works, but everytime when i try to run it from VBA it crashes with error-code 1004 and tells me the problemn is in code *.Range("C29").Formula = "=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$19:$A$1000;$B29;Sheet1!$G$19:$G$1000)"*.

Changed the formula to simplere formulas and that works fine.
Anybody else who knows this issue?

```
Sub FillDown()

    Dim strFormulas '(1 To 3) As Variant 

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainSheet")


        .Range("C29").Formula = "=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$19:$A$1000;$B29;Sheet1!$G$19:$G$1000)"
 
        .Range("C29:C501").FillDown
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: This has been asked so many times and I'm too tired to search for the best duplicate answer. You need to specify the formula in US-English when writing it with VBA. Replace the `;` by `,`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51399429/7599798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub FillDown2()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MainSheet")
     
    ws.Range("C29").FormulaLocal = "=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$19:$A$1000;$B29;Sheet1!$G$19:$G$1000)"
    ws.Range("C29:C501").FillDown
End Sub
```

So the problemn was based in the settings of my worksheet.
By adding the formulalocal and at least i now dont have the bug anymore, on to the next problemn xD

Comment: If this worked for you remember to mark it as the accepted answer (should be a tick on the left somewhere).

Comment: Note that by using `FormulaLocal`, the code will no longer work for anyone not using the same language settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SUMIF formular. It contains error.Is your idea `"=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$19:$A$1000, $B29, Sheet1!$G$19:$G$1000)"`??

Comment: The local settings uses ";" instead of ",".
In my case off-course.