# Type Mismatch in Excel Vba using Vlookup() Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am new to VBA. I wrote the following macro that gives me a 'type-mismatch' error (run-time error: 13).

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Set myrange = Sheet1.Range("B4081:F4094")
Sheet1.Cells(1634, 13).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1694, 2) & myrange & ", 2, False)"
End Sub
```

Ultimately, my intention is to use a drop-down list along with a vlookup so that selecting the drop-down value changes the multiple associated values in other columns in the same row. This small macro is supposed to be a part of the bigger one. Earlier, I was using something like this:

```
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2), myrange, 2, False)
```

The problem with this was that it didn't show the associated values when I selected an option from the drop-down. I guessed that may be I am changing the value using vlookup, which is a fixed, one-time event that happens when I click the commandbutton. So, I replaced this with a formula, thinking that due to the formula, values will change as and when I select an entry from the drop-down.

I need to submit a work constituting 9 sheets, in each of which I have to do this, hence the VBA. Seems like some quick help is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the issue here is that you're missing a comma in your formula before `myrange`.

Comment: **a simple typographical error.** Close question?

Comment: @dwirony - that + `.Address` twice.

Comment: @PGCodeRider - 3 errors actually. `.Address` is quite important.

Comment: @Vityata Very true, but that's just because they decided to use a `Range` instead of just a `String` or something to represent that part of the `VLOOKUP`. Regardless I upvoted your answer because it's the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

`VLOOKUP()` has 3 important parameters, which should be passed. In your case, you are passing 2 of the parameters as `Range()`, which is an object in VBA, and you need the `Address` property of the object.

Long story short, change the `.Formula` line to this:

```
Sheet1.Cells(1634, 13).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Sheet1.Cells(1694, 2).Address & _
                                        "," & myRange.Address & ", 2, False)"
```

Or if you need some minimal example:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("D1:E10")
    Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(2, 2).Address & "," _
                                & myRange.Address & ", 2, False)"

End Sub
```

This is a good example of `.Formula` usage in Excel, when you are having the formula functioning correctly:

- [Excel VBA Formula German/French/Italian/Russian/Dutch/Foreign Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363434/excel-vba-formula-german-french-italian-russian-dutch-foreign-function)