# Issue with FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba, formula, excel-r1c1-notation

I need a little help with the below formula in VBA:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3,'Int Data'!D:J,7,0),"")
```

I've tried to run the following:

```
Range("AP2").Select    
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR((VLOOKUP(RC[-1],(J3,'Agent Table'!D:J,7,0),"")"    
Range("AP2").Select    
Selection.Copy    
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False    
Cells.Select    
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

When I try to run this statement -

`ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR((VLOOKUP(RC[-1],(J3,'Agent Table'!D:J,7,0),"")"`

I got a:

> Run-time error '1004'

Can you please advise what is wrong with this statement?

Comment: Welcome to SO. My eyes could be wrong but I'm pretty sure that VLOOKUP has only 4 arguments, and in your formula you have 5. Your formula is `VLOOKUP(RC[-1],(J3,'Agent Table'!D:J,7,0)`. Should it not be `VLOOKUP(J3,'Agent Table'!D:J,7,0)` ??? That would fit your example of `VLOOKUP(J3,'Int Data'!D:J,7,0)`. 4 Arguments, not 5.

Comment: Besides, parenthesis quantity must be the same in both cases always, but you have 4 `(` and only 2 `)`. Something is wrong there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `.FormulaR1C1` and not `.Formula`:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R3C10,'Agent Table'!C4:C10,7, 0)"""")"`

`R3C10` is the `R1C1` notation for `J3`.

If you are using the Macro Recorder to see the formula, select "Use Relative References" in the developer tab to change the way the address is displayed:

[image]

Comment: Hi Vityata, I tried your suggestion but regrettably, it doesn't work. I'm not trying to record the macro though. Thanks

Comment: @MarkH - I know you are not trying to record the macro. This is just in case, if you were trying to. In general, write a formula in Excel, select it and run the code from here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49363501/5448626 It will print you the correct code in the format you select. E.g. replace `strFormula = Selection.Formula` with `strFormula = Selection.FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: Thanks again Vityata but still no luck with it. Still the same error message. Any other thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @MarkH - what did you get as a result in the immediate window after using the function from the linked answer in my previous comment?

Comment: @MarkH - actually in the formula `J3` is not passed in R1C1 format.

Comment: Both reference must be in same format either R1C1 or A1

Comment: `'Agent Table'!D:J` should be `'Agent Table'!C4:C10`

Comment: Also there are too many `(`: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R3C10,'Agent Table'!C4:C10,7,0),"""")"`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I have edited while improving the preivous one :)

Comment: Still need to fix the `""` to `""""`

Comment: Just one question. How do you know the area to search is `C4:C10` instead of `D:J`? :O

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns C4:C10 in R1C1 is columns D:J.

Comment: Omg!!!!! Facepalm! Thanks @ScottCraner I read that still as `A1` style. My bad. Thanks for aclaration

Comment: To be honest, since seeing this approach - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363434/excel-vba-formula-german-french-italian-russian-dutch-foreign-function/49363501#49363501 I have never ever tried anything else.

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks very much for rectifying my line. It does work perfectly.

Comment: @MarkH, If this answer worked, please, mark it as correct so it can help future users. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are combining A1 and R1C1 referencing in the same formula, this should be avoided.

Generally R1C1 is the preferred reference style for VBA. It may require a few more keystrokes but it provides greater control when accessing the cells.