# Formula returns #Name? although it's correct in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a Excel VBA script that puts a formula in a Cell:

```
objsubSheet.Cells(i + 4, 2).Formula = "=" & "MITTELWERT(B4:B" & i + 2 & ")"
```

This works fine, but the formula is returning an error:

```
Invalide Name
```

Now the funny thing begins, when I mark the cell and open the Editor Mode with F2 and click ENTER, the formula magically works:

[image]

The cells from where the formula gets the values, also got there values form a formula entered by the VBA script and they work perfectly fine. Currently working on a Excel 2016.

Does anyone knows what is the Problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in a German-speaking country, but Excel is an English based software. Excel throws an error, because using `.Formula` it expects a English formula, and it is not getting it.

So, instead of `.Formula`, you should use `.FormulaLocal` to use the local German formulas:

`objsubSheet.Cells(i + 4, 2).FormulaLocal = "=MITTELWERT(B4:B" & i + 2 & ")"`

- [Excel VBA Formula German/French/Italian/Russian/Dutch/Foreign Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363434/excel-vba-formula-german-french-italian-russian-dutch-foreign-function)

Comment: Thank you, this also fixed my problems with semicolons and commas!

Comment: @schoche - you are welcome.

Comment: Plus one just because you worked out that OP was from Germany :)

Comment: Please @Zac, don't retract your vote, but OP was not and is not from Germany:). They are from a german speaking country nevertheless, namely "Österreich" (Austria)

Comment: @TomBrunberg - yeah updated as well.